# About root directory's filesystem and partitioning

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, arch-linux

Iam a new user of linux and I am trying to really get the hang of it before i use arch (I know it is a hard choice for a beginner but i love to dive in so i can understand more).

Basically, my problem is that when i create partitions on the hard drive and then mount them from what i know it does not actually matter where you mount them specifically as long as it is in the root directory, so when i watched how to do that what i've seen is that they mount them most of the time in the /mnt even the root partition is inside the /mnt so how could that be possible because if you mount it inside the /mnt where would the rest of the root directory reside in the harddisk because it will not have a place to be to then make it possible to the system to reach /mnt in the first place.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The same partition or filesystem can be mounted at various different places at different times. The mount point is *not* a persistent property of the filesystem, but a purely in-memory one.

In other words, Linux does not remember where you've mounted something, and it doesn't actually affect how files are stored on disk – the mounts done in the installation "live USB" are temporary and don't carry over through reboots. Every time the system boots, it has to re-do *all* mounts from scratch.

So during every boot, Linux looks at the `root=` kernel parameter and mounts that partition directly at `/` i.e. the root. (Then it looks in the /etc/fstab file to know where to mount the rest, such as /home.)

> so when i watched how to do that what i've seen is that they mount them most of the time in the /mnt even the root partition is inside the /mnt

Imagine taking out the C:\ disk from one Windows PC and connecting it to another as a data disk via USB. It'll show up as E:\ or something. It's still the same disk, but it got mounted on a different drive letter (because you still have your "running" system at C:).